# Plotting Trajectory Graph in C with Arrays

Tags: c, arrays, math, graph

First time posting a question - let's hope I build a good reputation!
The title pretty much describes the nature of my assignment:

> After a user enters the Initial Speed and Launch Angle for a projectile, my program has to generate points and plot a graph of the projectile's trajectory. For this I must use two 2D arrays - one for the points generated and the other as a canvas (basically an 40x80 empty array filled with spaces).

I was given the prototypes for the functions that I must use, so here is the relevant code I've come up with (it is quite lengthy, but only for completeness' sake. The actual questions can be found in the 3rd and 4th functions):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "Assignment6B.h"

int Sx = 0;
int Sy = 0;
void calcTraj(double initSpeed, double launchAngle, double trajData[][2]) {
    do {
        double Ux = initSpeed*cos(launchAngle*3.14/180.0);
        double Uy = initSpeed*sin(launchAngle*3.14/180.0);
        Sy = (Sx/Ux)*(Uy - ((9.81*Sx)/(2*Ux)));
        if (Sy >= ZERO) {
            trajData[Sx][0] = Sx;
            trajData[Sx][1] = Sy;
        }
        Sx++;
    } while (Sy >= ZERO);
}

int Row, Column;
void clearDisplayData(char displayData[HEIGHT][WIDTH]) {
    for (Row = 0; Row < HEIGHT; Row++) {
        for (Column = 0; Column < WIDTH; Column++) {
            displayData[Row][Column] = ' ';
        }
    }
}

void updateDisplayData(char displayData[HEIGHT][WIDTH], double trajData[][2]) {
```

This is the part where I am stuck and quite hopelessly clueless.

I understand the idea behind the function: It receives the "empty canvas" array as well as the array containing the data (points for the graph). So, what needs to be done now, is all the elements in `displayData` that correspond with the `[Sx][Sy]`-coordinates in `trajData`, need to be replaced with an `X`. E.g., say `[1][4]` in `trajData` has an element, then `displayData[1][4]` = `X`.

I just have no idea how to code this. If someone could supply a sample, that would be great!

```
}

void printData(char displayData[HEIGHT][WIDTH]) {
    puts("");
    for (Column = 0; Column < WIDTH + 2; Column++) {
        printf("_");
    }
    puts("");
    for (Row = 0; Row < HEIGHT; Row++) {
        printf("|");
        for (Column = 0; Column < WIDTH; Column++) {
            printf("%c", displayData[Row][Column]);
        }
        printf("|");
        puts("");
    }
    for (Column = 0; Column < WIDTH + 2; Column++) {
        printf("_");
    }
```

This function is also not entirely correct. I have to plot a graph, which means the point `[0,0]` has to be in the bottom-left corner. But element `[0][0]` of an array is in the top-left.

I think that the order in which the rows are displayed should then just be reversed with a `for`-loop, e.g. `for (Row = HEIGHT; Row > 0; Row--)` - right? Please advise...
}

If anyone notices any other problems or has any advice, please share! Everything that helps is appreciated...

Comment: The caller of `calcTraj` has to ensure that the array `trajData` is big enough to hold all points being calculated (otherwise `calcTraj` is writing beyond the end of the array). While this is certainly possible, it seems risky.

Answer (score 0):

Ashton, if I'm not mistaken, the conceptual difficulty you seem to be having is only partly related to C (syntax wise). The other part is simply understanding what you are being asked to do with the two separate arrays. I'll take a stab at clearing the fog and hopefully won't make it worse. This is basically a data-scaling problem.

Your two arrays `trajData` and `displayData` are simply two different representations of the same data. `trajData` holds the full values, `displayData` will simply hold the same values scaled to fit in `[HEIGHT][WIDTH]`.

Your `trajData` holds the values returned from the kinematic equations for any given point in time. Your `displayData` is simply an array holding what would be printed to the screen if you were to print the contents of `trajData` to some `[HEIGHT][WIDTH]` display. This is where your work is.

In order to fit `trajData` into the `[HEIGHT][WIDTH]` constraints of `displayData`, you need to calculate two scale factors. The first will scale the difference between `HEIGHTMAX - HEIGHTMIN` so all your *Y-value* data points fit in `HEIGHT`. Your second scale factor will insure all your time values (number of iterations you calculated points for, e.g. `while (Sy >= ZERO);`) will fit in `WIDTH`. (this also means you will need to return (or update a pointer) with the number of points in `trajData`.

Since you are currently using `type void`, change the return type to something useful, say `unsigned int` or `size_t` or simply `int` (even though there is no negative time) and return the number of points) Always choose your return type so that it returns some information of value to you. A `void` return (not to be confused with `void *`) should only be used when there is nothing of use to return, like for functions that simply `print` data or `free` memory, etc.

Knowing the number of points and knowing the range of `'Y'` values, you can calculate factors to scale your `trajData` values. These scale factors will limit the values that you will use to fill `displayData` so it all fits and so you don't commit the error of writing beyond the end of your array.

Your goal with the `displayData` array (after clearing) is simply to *turn-on* the cells that hold the `trajData` values scaled to fit in `[HEIGHT][WIDTH]`. To use the scale you would need to know the range of both `Sx` and `Sy`, so you could add a few variables such as:

```
int Sx = 0;
int Sy = 0;
int y_min = INT_MAX;
int y_max = INT_MIN;
```

Then you will need to pick off the max/min values for `Sy` in `calcTraj` something similar to:

```
int calcTraj(double initSpeed, double launchAngle, double trajData[][2]) {

    ... 
    if (Sy >= ZERO) {
        if (Sy > y_max) y_max = Sy;
        if (Sy < y_min) y_min = Sy;
        ...
    } while (Sy >= ZERO);

    return Sx;
}
```

To compute the scale factor, you will do something similar to:

```
int scale_x = WIDTH/Sx;
int scale_y = HEIGHT/(y_max - y_min);
```

For filling `displayData`, you will just want to turn on the cells with whatever character you want to display the trajectory path, say `'X'` or `'#'` or `'*'`. Something like the following should be close, but **note**, since you are using integer division, you may have to adjust the scaling formula used where `HEIGHT` is less than `(y_max - y_min)`, or change to a different intermediate data type like `float` or `double` to accurately scale your values.

Also, if `Sx` is vastly larger than `WIDTH` you may be writing several `'Y'` values for each `'X'` value where the slope of the trajectory become vertical -- like the plot for shooting a bullet straight up. (you can average if you must only give 1 value). Something like the following should work:

```
/* set each relative cell to 'X' */
for (i = 0; i < Sx; i++) {
    displayData[scale_x * trajData[i][0]][scale_y * trajData[i][1]] = 'X';
}
```

**Note:** these are just thoughts on the issue and I haven't coded a complete example to test. So if you run into issues, let me know.

Comment: Firstly, I'd like to thank you for the answer. It seems you spent a decent amount of time to thoroughly explain these concepts. What I've learned now is certainly very interesting - especially the scale factor idea - but it is not exactly fitting for the assignment. Which brings me to my next point...

Comment: Damn it. Didn't realize "Enter" would post it. Anyway, I'd like to apologize for not being precise enough in my description of the assignment. Here is an important point I had not included: A scale is already defined. In that empty 40x80 array, we were told that each line and space represented 1 metre. So a scale factor wouldn't be allowed. Your explanation of how the two arrays actually held the same data really helped me in writing the code for `updateDisplayData` with which I struggled earlier. My program now works - for the most part. I will follow up in another post...

Comment: Ahh, that's precicely where I think you will run into needing the exact scale I provided. You see, it doesn't matter whether you call the `40x80` scale feet, meters, or angstroms, you still need to map the raw range of your `trajData` into the `40x80` space. Meaning if you have 200 points in `trajData`, they still must be mapped to fit into a `WIDTH` of 40. Work through it, you have something else not apparent yet that does that, but from what you have posted so far, you can't  avoid using an explicit scale. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Finally! I have completed my program and it works satisfactorily...

> The completed code follows. I add it only so that someone who might have the same problem, can see the desired result.

Note, however, that this program isn't built for accuracy, but rather as a test of the skill, knowledge and capability of C beginners...

*Header File:*

```
#ifndef ASSIGNMENT6B_H_
#define ASSIGNMENT6B_H_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

// Constants (of array to serve an "canvas" for graph and calculations)
#define WIDTH   80
#define HEIGHT  40
#define g       9.81
#define ZERO    0.0

// Function Prototypes
void calcTraj(double initSpeed, double launchAngle, double trajData[WIDTH][2]);
void clearDisplayData(char displayData[HEIGHT][WIDTH]);
void updateDisplayData(char displayData[HEIGHT][WIDTH], double trajData[WIDTH][2]);
void printData(char displayData[HEIGHT][WIDTH]);

#endif /* ASSIGNMENT6B_H_ */
```

*Functions:*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "Assignment6B.h"

void calcTraj(double initSpeed, double launchAngle, double trajData[WIDTH][2]) {
    int Sx = 0;
    int Sy = 0;
    //assign all values in array to 0
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            trajData[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    double Ux = initSpeed*cos(launchAngle*M_PI/180.0);      //Horizontal component of velocity
    double Uy = initSpeed*sin(launchAngle*M_PI/180.0);      //Vertical component of velocity
    do {
        Sy = (Sx/Ux)*(Uy - ((g*Sx)/(2*Ux)));                //Calculates y-value of position for every x used
        if (Sy >= ZERO) {
            //Stores data in a table form
            trajData[Sx][0] = Sx;
            trajData[Sx][1] = Sy;
        }
        Sx++;
    } while (Sy >= 0 && Sx <= 80 && Sx >= 0);               //Executed only for as long as projectile is air-borne
}                                                           //and within graphing range

//Assigns spaces to all elements of the "canvas",
//i.e. creates an empty array with the desired dimensions
void clearDisplayData(char displayData[HEIGHT][WIDTH]) {
    int Row, Column;
    for (Row = 0; Row < HEIGHT; Row++) {
        for (Column = 0; Column < WIDTH; Column++) {
            displayData[Row][Column] = ' ';
        }
    }
}

//Merges the two arrays,
//i.e. adds all data (coordinates) for trajData to displayData to create the graph
void updateDisplayData(char displayData[HEIGHT][WIDTH], double trajData[WIDTH][2]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {
        if (HEIGHT - (int)floor(trajData[i][1]) >= 0) {
            displayData[HEIGHT - (int)floor(trajData[i][1])][(int)floor(trajData[i][0])] = '*';
        }
    }
}

//Prints graph and border
void printData(char displayData[HEIGHT][WIDTH]) {
    int Row, Column;
    puts("");
    for (Column = 0; Column < WIDTH + 2; Column++) {
        printf("_");
    }
    puts("");
    for (Row = 0; Row < HEIGHT; Row++) {
        printf("|");
        for (Column = 0; Column < WIDTH; Column++) {
            printf("%c", displayData[Row][Column]);
        }
        printf("|");
        puts("");
    }
    for (Column = 0; Column < WIDTH + 2; Column++) {
        printf("_");
    }
}
```

*Main:*

```
#include "Assignment6B.h"

double initSpeed, launchAngle;
char displayData[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
double trajData[WIDTH][2];
int a;

int main() {

    do {

        //Clear display (on Windows)
        system("cls");

        setbuf(stdout, 0);

        clearDisplayData(displayData);

        printData(displayData);

        //Values to be entered by user and used in functions
        printf("\n\nEnter the Initial Speed of the particle: ");
        scanf("%lf", &initSpeed);
        printf("\nEnter the Launch Angle of the particle: ");
        scanf("%lf", &launchAngle);

        calcTraj(initSpeed, launchAngle, trajData);

        updateDisplayData(displayData, trajData);

        printData(displayData);

        //Allows user to repeat or exit
        printf("\n\nType a '0' to exit; any other number to continue: ");
        scanf("%d", &a);

    } while (a != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

And that's it! Feel free to comment, rate, vote or whatever - and thank you, Stack Overflow people!